# Rails custom mail relay address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a rails app where I want to mask a customer's email address by providing them with a dummy one. Similar to Apples [Private Relay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212614). So for example, if a user is currently has an account whose email is `johndoe@example.com`, I would like to create an email similar to `fakeemail123@example.com`. However, I still want `fakeemail123@example.com` to be able to reach `johndoe@example.com`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since rails 6 you can use [Action Mailbox](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#what-is-action-mailbox-questionmark) for this.

If your rails version is lower than 6 consider upgrading or otherwise you'll need to host a mail server on your own. [Postfix](https://www.postfix.org) is a good choice and somebody shared a sample configuration [here](https://serverfault.com/a/505508).